# User has read access in folder level.But he can able to update file in that folder. Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I am facing one issue :

A user has read access to a folder, which has unique permissions. But he is able to update the file whereas he should not update or upload the file. That user has read permissions to site and also list level.
Can anyone provide suggestions  on this ASAP.

I tried checking permissions of the file and the user also has read access and also he doesn't have any unique permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Does the file inherit the permissions of the folder?

I suggest you remove the user's read permission for the file, then re-grant the use with read permission.